# How can I approximate a function with composite polynomials?

Tags: fitting, polynomials, approximation

I know that to approximate a function with for example $f(x) = \sin(x)$ using polynomials with degrees up to 4, I can use the `Fit` function :

```
f[x_] := Sin[x];
p1 = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}];

theTable = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
thePoly = Table[x^i, {i, 0, 4}]
theFit = Fit[theTable, thePoly, x]
p2 = Plot[theFit, {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}];
Show[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

Now I want to approximate $f(x) = \sin(x)$ with a composite function with degree up to 4, which means it is $g(h(x))$ where $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are both polynomials with the sum of the degrees less than or equal to 4, how can I do it?

Comment: Check document of `FindFit`

Comment: Any special reason for limiting possibilities to compositions?

Comment: To composite polynomials of degree 4 are a polynomial of degree 16.

Comment: @DanielHuber I took “sum of the degrees” to mean deg(g)+deg(h). Maybe I misunderstand though.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau If deg[g]+deg[h]=4,   that would give only 2 non trivial cases. deg(g)==deg(h)==2, that is {2,2}, results in a quartic poly.  And  {3,1} and {1,3}  result in a third order poly. And {0,4}, {4,0} would be constants.